# How to get paid in iOS app without a 30% cut

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment

I am developing an iOS app and I would like to receive payments within the app. I am selling a "real" good/service, so my profit margin on each sale is only around 20%. I can't afford to pay Apple 30% on each purchase made within the app.

What are my options for accepting payment without giving Apple a 30% cut?

Comment: You don't use Apple's in-app purchasing for real world sales.

Comment: totally irrelevant here on this site

Comment: I want to know what API's are available for accepting payments. Can I use an Apple API, Apply Pay, PayPal, etc.? This seems relevant to me

Comment: If memory serves the app store explicitly states that it is not for use in sale of real world goods and services. You should be able to use a web service to collect payments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming as defined in the [help]

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I have created and offer a standalone solution payment acceptance solution for small businesses.

The actual answer to the question you asked is, "select and integrate any of the various payment processors", but that's not very helpful.

I would second the other answer about looking for canned solutions unless you absolutely need to control the whole experience.

If you do still want to go down the roll-your-own route, you will need an enhanced vocabulary and some time to research on your own. First suggestion: look for relevant questions/answers on the net for "iOS app payment processing". The search engine of your choice should lead you to many possible answers from which you can refine your question or even, perhaps, find an outright answer that works for you.

You'll need to understand how you expect to capture payment information, process that payment into "money", and how you will manage your back-end. For example, you could use Apple Pay, but that by itself doesn't actually solve any of your actual payment processing issues (not to mention very likely unfavorably restricts your customer base if that's all you do).

Do alternatives like Stripe, Braintree, and more have their own APIs? Yes. Can they be used *with* Apple Pay? Yes. You could try implementing them then coming back here with specific questions.

Separate out questions like "How do implement Stripe payment processing?" from questions of the type "What are some of the options for knowing when an item needs to be shipped, where to, and when it has been accepted?" (Which won't be appreciated here -- you'll also need to research/write at least an attempt at this before asking.) Each type of question will need to have a "show your work so far" component as well as a clear (as much as possible) problem description in order to get responses that are pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

Real world goods don't need to be set up through in-app purchases. You can use other services such as [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) or [Authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/mobilemerchantaccount/) to set up payment flows in your app that way.

Note that you'll most likely also need a web service and server backend aspect as you'll need a centralized location to keep track of your real goods inventory and perform the actual transactions of charging your customers, updating the inventory and starting the process of fulfillment. Of course, this isn't true if you're creating an app to manage payments of your flea market sales, but in that case, you really should be looking to use an existing app solution like [Square](https://squareup.com/signup) since you'll still be subject to charges when using Stripe and Authorize as well.